# Python-how to pass functions in df to.csv

Tags: python

I have this:

```
dfsql = client.query(sql, project=project_id).to_dataframe()
filename = f"divyangtest_{str(datetime.datetime.now()).split('.')[0].replace(' ', '_')}.csv"
dfsql.to_csv('/home/analytics/divyang/filename')
```

But when I pass this, it creates just a filename as the csv, not the file which I wanted.

Can anyone tell me how to pass that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the variable `filename` the same way you passed the datetime before:

```
dfsql = client.query(sql, project=project_id).to_dataframe()

filename = f"divyangtest_{str(datetime.datetime.now()).split('.')[0].replace(' ', '_')}.csv"

dfsql.to_csv(f"/home/analytics/divyang/{filename}")
```

Answer (score 0):

odirpath='/home/analytics/divyang/'

dfsql = client.query(sql, project=project_id).to_dataframe()

filename = f"divyangtest_{str(datetime.datetime.now()).split('.')[0].replace(' ', '_')}"
dfsql.to_csv(odirpath+filename+'.csv',index=False,encoding='utf-8')

its running